# Crossfire Setup - 5 Monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, crossfire

I have 2x HD7950 graphics cards, each with a HDMI, DVI and 2x Mini Display Port outputs. Currently I have this with crossfire enabled, and 4 monitors running 1920 x 1080 on each. The display ports are using an active DVI and active HDMI adapter to plug into the monitors.

I wish to add a 5th monitor (actually a projector) running at 1280 x 720. I can do so without an issue by disabling crossfire, then simply using HDMI on the second card. I wish to use both cards to their full ability though, so is there a way I can set this up with all 5 monitors running, with crossfire still enabled?

Thanks all.

P.s. Eyefinity is not required.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [crossfire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD_CrossFireX) (or [SLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Link_Interface)) then you use the other graphical card **only** for calculations. You can not use it to output a signal to a monitor.

So briefly: No, there is not way you can set this up with all 5 monitors running with crossfire still enabled.

You can either:

1. Disable crossfire and gain access to the four ports on the other card.
2. Temporarily disable crossfire when you want to do this, and only use four (or fewer) displays when gaming.
3. Or add a third card, not as part of the crossfire setup.
4. Or use a third party item to split the output from one of the cards to multiple displays. E.g. [something like this](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/th2go/displayport/). But you use it like that feel like a kludge.